# Arquillian with wildfly 10

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, integration-testing, jboss-arquillian, wildfly-10

Looking for a tutorial on Arquillian with wildfly 10.
I have tried this [tutorial](http://reallifejava.com/arquillian-with-wildfly-8/) 
I am getting the following error when I try to run it.
Caused by:

```
org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.embedded:main
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:240)
at org.jboss.as.embedded.EmbeddedServerFactory.create(EmbeddedServerFactory.java:119)
at org.jboss.as.embedded.EmbeddedServerFactory.create(EmbeddedServerFactory.java:99)
at org.jboss.as.embedded.EmbeddedServerFactory.create(EmbeddedServerFactory.java:82)
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.embedded.EmbeddedDeployableContainer.setup(EmbeddedDeployableContainer.java:47)
```

Comment: Hi guyz, got this solved, and this works fine with the wildfly 8.0 and if you want to work with 10.0 its just the matter of changing the version in POM

Comment: Please write an answer with your solution instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got this solved, and this works fine with the wildfly 8.0 and if you want to work with 10.0 its just the matter of changing the version in POM